entityframework core8で同じテーブル構造のテーブル名を動的に切り分ける
asp.net coreの.net8でblazorのwebアプリを作成しています。
今まではORMはDapperを使用していたのですが、今回ef coreを初めて利用しています。
すでに存在しているDB（Sqlserver）をdotnet efコマンドを使用してscaffoldしてモデルとdbcontextを作成しました。
このDBの中には「テーブル名A2024」のように末尾に年数がついたテーブルが複数存在しています。
もちろんこれらのテーブルはscaffoldingでは別々のテーブルとして生成されているのですが、これらをアプリケーションから呼び出したときに引数などに年数を指定して取得できるようにしたいと考えています。
このようなことは可能なのでしょうか？
もちろん動的にSQL自体を記述すれば可能なのでしょうが、できるだけそれはしたくはありません。
お力添えいただけるとありがたいです。

「アプリケーションから呼び出したときに引数などに年数を指定して取得できるようにしたい」<= 理解できません。ASP.NET Core アプリですよね？　何をどうしたいのか、もっと詳しく、できれば具体的な例を書いていただけませんか？

EF Coreで同じモデルを複数のテーブルにマッピングする こちらの回答で解決できました。
コメントいただいたのに申し訳ないです。
